# handling keywrod while using get_json_object in HIVE

Tags: hive, getjson

I have a JSON which I am trying to parse in HIVE using get_json_object built-in function. In my JSON there is a key like "timestamp", where my parsing is failing because "timestamp" is identified as a keyword.

I am trying to use `select get_json_object(col1,'$.timestamp') as ts from table1`.

How can the keyword be handled while using get_json_object in HIVE?

Answer (score 0):

Run this to have the keywords ignored.

SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;